# jQuery Tools Scrollable fluid width

Tags: jquery-tools, scrollable

I wonder if anyone knows of a way to have the jQuery tools Scrollable plugin scroll content in a fluid layout/100% width.

It's a news scroller on an intranet site. I have it working awesome with fixed width but am moving to a fluid width layout and cannot get it to work as it's setup only to work with a fixed width.

If anyone knows of any alternatives, that will slide text at fluid width with a navigation, I would love to hear about them.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make scrollable responsive is to add javascript to calculate the screen/browser/viewport width on display and then set this within your HTML.

See http://cooshtee.com/blog/2013/04/making-jquery-tools-scrollable-responsive/ for example code.